# Как заменить входящее число как количество знаков после точки?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно в упрощеном виде реализовать такую функцию замены?

Или еще лучше без внешней функции, если в js есть какие то встроенные функции и возвращаться обязательно ввиде строки.

```
// примеры:
var min = 2;
var min2 = 3;
var min3 = 7;

// заменить на:
var min = "0.01";
var min2 = "0.001";
var min3 = "0.0000001";

// например:
var min = myfunction(2); // вызывается функция и она возвращает строку "0.01"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let myfunction = (number) => `0.${'0'.repeat(number - 1)}1`;

console.log(myfunction(2));
console.log(myfunction(3));
console.log(myfunction(7));
```